# build sqlsmith autoreconf: 'configure.ac' or 'configure.in' is required

Tags: configure, autoreconf

I followed the instructions to install sqlsmith
One of the libraries installation instructions are

```
brew install libpqxx automake libtool autoconf autoconf-archive pkg-config
cd sqlsmith
autoreconf -i # Avoid when building from a release tarball
./configure
make
```

I have a problem at

```
autoreconf -i
```

the error is

```
autoreconf: 'configure.ac' or 'configure.in' is required
```

But when I install autoreconf, I have the newest version.

```
autoconf is already the newest version (2.69-9).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 26 not upgraded.
```

What could be wrong?